# If two tables have a "One To One" relationship, should they have the same column as primary key?

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a table called `Users` which represents registered users of a website. I also have an `AccountActivation` table which stores the randomly generated string sent to a new user's email to verify that email.

The `AccountActivation` table has `UserId` column which also happen to be the primary key for the `Users` table. It also has the `ActivationCode` column to store the code. Either column could uniquely identify a row in the `AccountActivation` table.

So if I choose the activation code column as the primary key, I end up having two one-to-one tables with different primary keys. I thought in one to one relationship, the two tables must have the same primary key?

Comment: If you choose `ActivationCode` as PK, then *why* do you have two *one-to-one* relations? The only relation that's there is `AccountActivation.UserId -> Users.UserId` - or what else do you think you suddenly have? `Users` has its PK on `UserId` and `AccountActivation` has its PK on `ActivationCode` - not a problem at all, no reason not to do it this way.

Comment: Most probably, "UserId" and "ActivationCode" are both candidate keys for the AccountActivation table.

Comment: How do you know that the same  randomly generated string won't be generated more than once and is it actually required by your application that you should enforce this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose `ActivationCode` as PK, then *why* do you have two *one-to-one* relations?

The only relation that's there is

```
AccountActivation.UserId -> Users.UserId
```

or what else do you think you suddenly have?

If go do what you suggested, then the table `Users` has its PK on `UserId` and table `AccountActivation` has its PK on `ActivationCode` - not a problem at all, and there's no reason not to do it this way.

Which column (`UserId` or `ActivationCode`) you pick for the PK of `AccountActivation` doesn't matter - that doesn't influence / disturb the FK relationship between `AccountActivation` and `User`, nor does it add an extra one-to-one relationship of any kind .....

If you do choose `ActivationCode` for the PK of `AccountActivation`, the only extra step that I would take is creating a nonclustered index on `UserId` so that queries that join the two tables will benefit from maximum performance.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only to be one `ActivationCode` they could share the `UserId`. But that would imply that when a user re-generated a key you should, either update the old row or delete it.

But why you need to store such data? You could also composite the account activation code with some sort of computation and encryption with unique data from the `User`.

Just to illustrate my suggestion:

```
Users table has two columns UserId CreationDate
```

Then the token might be `UserId + CreationDate` (example). You would be able to generate and check it without the extra data in the database. I know that this might not suite your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Make the UserId column in the AccountActivation a foreign key to the Users table.

```
Users
=====

UserId primary key
Name
Address
etc...

AccountActivation 
=================

UserId primary key (foreign key to Users.UserId)
ActivationCode (unique constraint)
```

Now you have a one-to-one relationship

Comment: Or in `AccountActivation` the `primary key` could be on `ActivationCode` and the unique constraint on `UserId`.

Comment: @MartinSmith - As long as the UserId is unique it will maintain the one-to-one relationship, otherwise, it becomes a one-to-many.

Comment: What was that in response to? I haven't suggested not making the `UserId` unique. If it was in response to my response to your deleted comment I was pointing out that a clustered index on `UserId,ActivationCode` wouldn't work as you can't enforce uniqueness on just part of the key.

Comment: @MartinSmith - why are you commenting on deleted comments??

Comment: What?! I was just asking why you addressed comment #2 in the trail to me as it doesn't seem to bear any relation to comment #1. I agree with  #2 but wasn't sure why you were telling me as comment #1 doesn't contradict that...

Answer (score 1):

You need not have the same column as primary key in 2 tables to have one-to-one relationship.
You can have any column as primary key in the `AccountActivation` table.

`UserId` which is the foreign key to the `AccountActivation` table is the primary key in `Users` table. So, you should definitely be able to uniquely identify a users activation code from the `AccountActivation` table using this column, no matter whether it is primary key of that table(But it should be unique and I hope it would).